# Как списывать деньги за минуту использования функции на arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

Всех приветствую.
Подскажите, как мне реализовать списание денег за минуту использования функции?
Есть цена функции, её надо растянуть на минуту и списывать с основного счёта, пока не кончатся деньги.

Мой код работает не правильно.

- cash - основной счёт.
- priceFunc - цена выбранной функции.
- btnName - название выбранной функции.

```
        if(millis() - Timer > 2000){
          Timer = millis();
          cash = cash-(priceFunc/30);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
          lcd.print(btnName);
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
          lcd.print(cash);
        }
      }
```

Comment: А что это вообще за код? Может, он работает неправильно, так как он не на Python? :-)

Comment: Кроме того, нет ни минимально воспроизводимого кода, ни описания, что не так в работе.

Comment: Это код для Arduino.

Comment: Сейчас эта часть кода работает не правильно. Т.е. сумма делится не на 60 а на не известно сколько.

Comment: К примеру: стоимость функции 35₽. На основном счету 35₽. И за 1 минуту списывает только 30, а должен все 35. В то же время если выставить 40₽ и зачислить 40₽, то по прошествии минуты, на остатке будет больше 5₽.

Comment: Потому и говорю что работает не правильно.

Comment: Я лично не понимаю, ни почему в неком Arduino используются в Python фигурные скобки таким образом (в стандартном синтаксисе такого не видел, это C какой-то или Java, вроде), ни почему их количество нечетное в данном случае, ни как вы предлагаете нам разбираться с вопросом, если нет  минимально воспроизводимого примера. Но я не так давно язык изучаю, может, кто и догадается.

Comment: А еще я не понимаю, почему, если написано в документации, как я сейчас увидел,  "Язык программирования устройств Ардуино основан на C/C++", то почему вы продолжате утверждать, что в данном случае это Python, даже когда я прямо выразил в этом сомнения.

Comment: Какой тип у `cash` и `priceFunc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в типах `cash` и `priceFunc`. Они у вас, очевидно, целочисленные - `int` или `short`.

Это приводит к ошибкам округления. Например, при `priceFunc==35` результат  `priceFunc/30 == 1`, и за одну минут от `cash` отнимается ровно 30.

Либо храните цену и вообще деньги в копейках (это предпочтительный вариант), т.е.

```
int cash = 3000;
int priceFunc=3500;

...

cash -= priceFunc / 30;
```

либо используйте тип `float`:

```
float cash = 30.0;
float priceFunc = 35.0;
```

Comment: Благодарю. Сегодня как попробую, отпишусь.

Comment: Супер! Всё заработало. Благодарю!